# Hash password different as before then can't login

Tags: php

Im just creating regis form and login page with hash password, but when im login the password is not match, its work before.

PHP/7.3.1
Apache/2.4.37
XAMPP v3.2.2

**register.php**

```
// Check error pada input sebelum memasukkan ke database
if(empty($firstname_err) && empty($lastname_err) && empty($gender_err) && empty($username_err) && empty($status_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

    // Mempersiapkan pemasukan stekmen database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, gender, username, status, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

        // Mem-bind variabel ke stekmen yang sudah disiapkan sebagai parameter
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $param_firstname, $param_lastname, $gender, $param_username, $param_status, $param_password);

        // Men-set parameter
        $param_firstname = $firstname;
        $param_lastname = $lastname;
        $param_gender = $gender;
        $param_username = $username;
        $param_status = $status;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Membuat sebuah hash password

        // Mencoba eksekusi stekmen yang sudah disiapkan
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){

            // Meng-redirect ke Halaman Login
            header("location: index.php");
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Ada yang salah. Silahkan coba lagi nanti.";
        }
    }

    // Menutup stekmen

}
```

**Login.php**

```
        // Mempersiapkan stekmen yang dipilih
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, status FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);   
            $param_username = $username;

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check jika username if already registered
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){   


   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password, $status);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){

                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                            $_SESSION["status"] = $status;                    

                            // Meng-redirect ke Halaman Home
                            header("location: welcome.php");

                        } } } } }        
        // Menutup stekmen
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
```

but i see, generated hash password is different before and idk what happened

Comment: is `$password` what you expect it to be?

Comment: What size is column in which you store the hashed passsword?

Comment: @Second2None hash password generated ex. like this $2y$10$EnIi90KP.0BqCVJgK21BrO3xzArxCZaiAPaUebCw.K2Xw71QOCZv2, but in database the hash password generated just half

Comment: @Jay, about 25, it's effect?

Comment: `$password` should be a plain text (by that I mean not hashed) string generally input by the user when you use `password_verify` can you update your code to show what how you get the `$password` and what you do with it.

Comment: @Second2None, u can see my code here, https://github.com/fatechid/learning-form/blob/master/register.php

Comment: But btw, thanks for @JayBlanchard i found the problem, cause size of the column is not enough for hashed password.

Comment: Correct. It needs to be at least 60 characters wide.